# Jackson Deserialize object as string

Tags: kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I have an json of the form

```
{
a: "a",
b: "b",
c: {
     d: "d",
     e: "e"
   }
}
```

I want to deserialize this to a class like this

```
class A {
String a;
String b;
String c
}
```

The following code throws an exception when trying to do this

```
val mapper = ObjectMapperBuilder().build()
        val request: RequestModel = mapper.readValue(sqsQueueMessage.body, RequestModel::class.java)
```

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value
```

Comment: that is not really a valid json, I don't know how jackson would process it. The keys need to be strings.

Comment: Share `RequestModel`  class